# What does George Andrews mean by i in "Theory of Partitions"?

Tags: integer-partitions

From the first page of chapter 1 of George Andrews "Theory of Partitions" (Rather ominous place to get stuck):

[image]

What do these last two sentences mean?  I don't get "where exactly $f_l$ of the $\lambda_j$ are equal to $i$."  Can one of you rephrase this for me, because I don't understand what $i$ is.

Comment: Is that better?  If not, feel free to edit it yourself.

Comment: Yes, much better, thanks.

Comment: I think, $l$ is $i$, just you have a poor quality copy.

Comment: @studiosus. That makes more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just means that the value $i$ is repeated $f_i$ times.  For example the notation $(1^42^23^04^15^1)$ means the same as $(1,1,1,1,2,2,4,5)$.  Since the parts have to add up to the integer $n$, the sum
$$\sum_{i\ge1}f_ii=n$$
in this example is just another (IMHO unnecessarily complicated) way of writing
$$1+1+1+1+2+2+4+5=17\ .$$

Comment: Oh.  I see now.  $i$ are the $\lambda_l$ that're repeated (for instance the values of i in yours are 1,2,3,4, and 5).  Thanks:  I knew it was something simple like that -- I was blanking when I looked at it.

Answer (score 2):

It means for example that $\lambda = (1^22^33^04^05^1)$ another notation for $\lambda = (1,1,2,2,2,5)$. That is the $f_l$ superscripts tells how many parts of a given size you have.